# Get all properties in an object array

Tags: clojure

I have a clojure object array; something similar to:

```
(def data {
    :genre "fantasy"
    :books [
        { :id 1 :name "Lord of the rings" }
        { :id 2 :name "Game of thrones" }
        { :id 3 :name "Harry potter" }]
    })
```

I want to get all the id of books.. something like `[1 2 3]`

I've tried a few things:

1. `(seq (data :books :id))`
2. `(data :books) :id)` `;results in an error, as expected`

But I can't figure out how to get the ids. Do I have to use a doseq or other iterator function to get the ids?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(->> data :books (map :id))
```

Comment: Hi, what does `(->>` mean, please?

Comment: @LocustHorde `(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(->> data :books (map :id)))    ;=> (map :id (:books data))`